# Spring Web/Security update to 5.1.1 breaking json response. json response now having escaped double quotes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

After updating from Spring Web version 4.2.8 to 5.1.1 and Spring Security 3.2.5 to 5.1.1 I'm now observing that the Spring implemented web controller method annotated with @ResponseBody is returning the json response with escaped double quotes whereas previously it was not. All " are now returned as \" in the json response. My html client code that calls this endpoint is breaking as a result. How can I disable this ? It feels like a feature that is now enabled by default but I can not find any information in the Spring documentation.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your controller and a response you are seeing?

Comment: Was able to resolve this issue by using the string transformer in the Spring config.